# Running Thinkorswim on Linux (Mint 19)

Tags: linux, linux-mint

> *This isn't so much of a question anymore as an answer since I figured it out. However I am hoping to help less tech savvy people with this in the future.*

I am running Linux Mint and I am trying to get thinkorswim to run. When I try to run it then it gives me "oracle JRE 8 update  11 or later on is required to run the application. Please manually update java and ensure it is the first java available in your system path"

[image: oracle JRE 8 update 11 or later on is required to run the application. Please manually update java and ensure it is the first java available in your system path]

I have Java 11 installed and it is the default, which I want to maintain for other programs. Instead I want to install Java 8 and run only this program in Java 8. I've already installed: openjdk-8-jdk, openjdk-8-jre, and the headless packages as well.

How do I launch thinkorswim using only Java 8 and without changing my system default to thinkorswim?

Related for basic install: https://askubuntu.com/questions/394062/running-thinkorswim

Comment: Try not installing the desktop shortcut and the start menu link. It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I tried a variety of things but the one thing that seemed to work best is by making my own executable script and replacing the desktop shortcut with it.

So open a text editor/nano/vi/etc file and name it thinkorswim2 (or whatever you want). In that put the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/:$PATH
exec  /home/user/thinkorswim/thinkorswim "$@"
```

Double check and make sure that the export path does match up on your system by following it. It just goes to the directory of the java executable.

If you followed the install script defaults then change user to be your home directory username. It installed to this directory by default for my version.

Now make that script executable. If you aren't used to the terminal than right click -> properties -> permissions -> allow executing file as program (or similar).

If your like me you want the same icon too so (in mint cinnamon) go to the basic tab in properties. Click the icon. Click browse and go to "/home/user/thinkorswim" then press ctrl + H while browsing to reveal hidden folders. go into "install4j" and pick "thinkorswim.png"

Hopefully this saves someone time in the future.